# Pandas DataFrame filtering with condition on other DataFrame, which no longer works on version 0.20.x

Tags: python, pandas

Up until Pandas version 0.19.2, below filtering worked

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df_filter = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 10], [2, 1, 7], [1, 8, 3], [3, 9, 4], [1, 20, 2], [1, 4, 8]]), columns=list('BCE'))
df[df_filter < 5]
```

and the output of `df` would be something like below (since it is random)

```
       A    B   C   D   E
0   0.257206    0.510411    -0.548331   -0.083934   1.824593
1   -1.534482   -1.073950   0.639955    0.351071    -1.897773
2   0.749863    0.152933    -0.960877   1.162595    0.374817
3   -0.360232   0.479257    0.956225    -0.039248   0.381733
4   -0.519164   0.188241    0.614066    -0.356650   -0.886236
5   0.314688    -1.021030   0.689874    1.723714    -1.487867
```

also the output of `df_filter`

```
    B   C   E
0   1   2   10
1   2   1   7
2   1   8   3
3   3   9   4
4   1   20  2
5   1   4   8
```

and the output of `df[df_filter < 5]`

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   NaN 0.510411    -0.548331   NaN NaN
1   NaN -1.073950   0.639955    NaN NaN
2   NaN 0.152933    NaN NaN 0.374817
3   NaN 0.479257    NaN NaN 0.381733
4   NaN 0.188241    NaN NaN -0.886236
5   NaN -1.021030   0.689874    NaN NaN
```

However, after Pandas version 0.20.x, `df[df_filter < 5]` no longer works and raises an exception.

Is there other ways I can do same filtering as I did above with Pandas version 0.19.2 on version 0.20.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to `reindex` the `(df_filter < 5)` mask

```
In [866]: df[(df_filter < 5).reindex(df.index, df.columns, fill_value=False)]
Out[866]:
    A         B         C   D         E
0 NaN -0.269032 -1.129067 NaN       NaN
1 NaN -0.048834  0.373961 NaN       NaN
2 NaN -0.210012       NaN NaN -0.763331
3 NaN -0.767513       NaN NaN  1.016767
4 NaN  0.255832       NaN NaN -1.494916
5 NaN -1.364790  0.345673 NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

For further context, this looks like a bug that appeared in version `0.20.3`, and then resolved itself on the current master branch.

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.21.0.dev+382.gd0d28fe'
>>> df[df_filter < 5]
    A         B         C   D         E
0 NaN  0.438217  1.266788 NaN       NaN
1 NaN  0.258682 -0.751940 NaN       NaN
2 NaN -0.046418       NaN NaN  0.018015
3 NaN  0.509749       NaN NaN -0.359434
4 NaN -1.682684       NaN NaN -0.758513
5 NaN  1.611907 -0.681083 NaN       NaN
```

As seen in [PR #1716](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17186), there has now been a test case added with behavior similar to yours to ensure that this issue won't reappear in future versions.

In the meantime, reindexing the mask as seen in [John Gait's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792433/4686625) seems like a reasonable fix.